# django-videothumbs and "list index out of range" error

Tags: django, video

Im using [django-videothumbs](https://github.com/macmichael01/django-videothumbs)
Video field is:

```
video = videothumbs.VideoThumbField(upload_to='videos', sizes=((125,125),(300,200),))
```

In uploading, video uploads but in thumbnail creation I have this error:

> Exception Value: list index out of range
>   Exception Location:/library/videothumbs.py in generate_thumb, line 51

And line 51:

```
for c in range(len(histogram[0])):
    ac = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
       ac = ac + (float(histogram[i][c])/n)
       avg.append(ac)
```

What is wrong about video filed?

Edit:
with `print histogram` I have:

```
sh: ffmpeg: command not found
```

But in terminal:

```
FFmpeg version CVS, Copyright (c) 2000-2004 Fabrice Bellard
Mac OSX universal build for ffmpegX
configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --enable-mp3lame --enable-gpl --disable-vhook --    disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-a52 --enable-xvid --enable-faac --enable-faad --enable-amr_nb --enable-amr_wb --enable-pthreads --enable-x264
libavutil version: 49.0.0
libavcodec version: 51.9.0
libavformat version: 50.4.0
built on Apr 15 2006 04:58:19, gcc: 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)
usage: ffmpeg [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of `histogram[0]`? Most probably `histogram` doesn't have any elements.

I would change the code in:

```
if len(histogram) > 0:
  for c in range(len(histogram[0])):
    ac = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
       ac = ac + (float(histogram[i][c])/n)
       avg.append(ac)
```

Comment: Don't need to check length .. 
just do it like
    if histogram:
        do something...

Comment: @Nicolae, I have edited my question. ffmpeg is installed but django could'nt find. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no knowledge of django-videothumbs, I was just noticed that small mistake in your code. In my opinion you should just make it as a separate question, because now the title and the initial premise are totally irrelevant, and either delete this question or accept an answer.